# Mongolia Course - Slides, Homework and Solutions

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know if we have access to the Mongolia course slides, homework and solutions? If so where can we find them? If not, please could they be made available? I think the homework exercises with solutions will be great practise for learning all the Haskell concepts as we follow the you tube videos.

Comment: Please note that the videos on github cover core content than the videos in YouTube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here
https://github.com/iohkedu/haskell-2020

videos, slides, homeworks and solutions

The videos here have way more content than in youtube